# Softlayer Endurance File Storage mounting in Ubuntu machines

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have two ubuntu machines and an Endurance file storage in dal 10 datacenter of Softlayer.

In the machine, I had installed
 apt-get -y install nfs-common

In the Softlayer control center File Storage ->  -> Authorized Hosts, added the machine using "Devices"

Then I tried to execute the command and got following error.

mount -t nfs -o hard,intr fsf-dal1001d-fz.adn.networklayer.com:/IBM02SEV571879_232/data01 /batch
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting fsf-dal1001d-fz.adn.networklayer.com:/IBM02SEV571879_232/data01

I tried with subnet authorising and IP way of authorising. Unfortunately same results

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried with another storage server and the issue resolved. It seems like there were some issues with a specified File Storage server in Softlayer.